# Darlington pair problem

Tags: power, current, gain, base, collector

[image: pair]

I was making a circuit using a Darlington pair with two [C3266](https://datasheetspdf.com/mobile/787760/ToshibaSemiconductor/C3266/1)  transistors and I noticed that the total gain doesn't amount to the expected value.

Instead of the total value be in accordance to the Darlington formula i.e (beta1*beta2)+(beta1+beta), I am only getting 2(beta1), or just twice the output of the first, even after connecting them in a Darlington configuration. The base current is 2.5 volts, 0.00035mA and Vce is 15 volts,100mA.

The datasheet says 290 (geometric average) DC current gain (@ 2V,100mA Vce.) My Vcc is 15 volt, 112mA.

Comment: Have you tested the transistors separately?

Comment: Yes i did... They showed positive response
They're all working

Comment: I do not understand why \$V_{CE}\$ and \$V_{CC}\$ come with a second measure in mA. From base current .35 μA to collector current 100 mA I get a factor about 300,000 - well above 2×100 or 2×290.

Comment: @greybeard suppose i have 1 ma to the base, then this amounts to 290ma for a single transistor. But with the pair, its going to be 84,680(theoretically). But i do end up with something like 580ma

Comment: Can you add a picture of the physical setup you get these numbers from?

Comment: @imranmuhd If it was 84 A, your transistors would melt. Your power supply is probably not capable of providing that much current in the first place. With gain as high as this, you need to measure with base currents on the order of microamps, not milliamps.

Comment: So supposed i attach a 10ohm 10 watts resistor to the output... Is it considerably accepted?

Comment: Incidentally, you've drawn something wrong on your circuit--as drawn, the base of your left transistor is just connected straight to ground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion became clear after some probing in the comments of your related (and now deleted) question where you explained that you are trying to make a lamp dimmer circuit. The problem appears to be that you think the bulb should be added in parallel with the Darlington transistor where the voltmeter is. This is not correct.

As you have drawn the circuit, when the lower transistor turns on it will short-circuit the power supply, a very high current will flow and the transistor will burn out.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxq0u2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. How to connect the lamp, where to connect an ammeter and where to connect a voltmeter.*

Now as Q2 is turned on current will flow from the power supply + through AM1, LAMP1 and Q2 back to the power supply.

Note that when the lamp is off that no current will flow and there is no need to waste power "dissipating" surplus power from the power supply.

In Figure 1 simulation I have set the potentiometer R2 at 0.5 (half-way) resulting in 6 V across the lamp and 60 mA *through* the lamp. Turning the potentiometer all the way up will roughly double those values. Turning R2 all the way down will decrease the meter readings to zero.

---

**Heatsinking**

As shown in Figure 1, there is 6 V dropped across the lamp so that means the remaining 6 V is dropped across Q2. Since there is 60 mA flowing through Q2 we can calculate the power dissipation in it. ***P = VI = 6 × 0.06 = 360* mW**. The transistor may get hot and you will have to check the datasheet to see how much power it can dissipate safely.

---

**Alternative dimmers**

What you are designing wastes energy as heat as we have shown above. At the half-way setting 50% of the power is consumed by the lamp and the other 50% is lost as waste heat. This is not efficient.

[image]

*Figure 2. PWM signal transitioning from high pulse width (75%) to low (25%) and back again. Note amplitude remains constant. You can read more I've written [here](http://lednique.com/power-supplies/dimmable-mains-psu-control/).*

Most modern dimmers will use pulse-width modulation (PWM) to switch the lamp fully on and fully off at a frequency higher than the eye can detect. This results in very little power lost as heat in the switching transistor.

---

Your schematic drawing shows a short-circuit around the potentiometer. This too will short-circuit the supply if wired as drawn.

Answer (score 1):

Ic = β*Ib is the formula that we all use.

If current Ib is too big then the BJT saturates and β decreases.

β is not a fixed value but depends on Ib.

In your project, the BJT on the right saturates because the current entering the Base is not limited by a resistor. As a consequence, β decreases.

If you read β = 100 in a datasheet of a BJT then you should read the value of Ib.